# почему плавный градиент в png , который я сделал в фотошопе, при загрузке из drawble-nodpi , становится резким?

Tags: java, android, android-drawable

Нарисовал в фотошопе фон , добавил градиент , сохраняю в png, есть возможность выбрать png -8 бит, 24 ,  выбираю 24, кидаю в папку drawble-nodpi, изображение 1920x1080 , экран телефона такой же . На экране качество изображения выдает резкий градиент, как будто я выбирал png-8 бит и использовал 64 цвета.. Вывод , что при загрузке в битмап , андроид сжимает изображение, чтобы в этом убедиться я могу узнать размер полученного битмапа (еще не сделал) Если потеря плавности градиент заключается в сжатие, то как убрать его?

Comment: Проблема может быть в том, что сам экран смартфона не воспроизводит градиент качественно. Просто закиньте в ваш смарт картинку с качественным градиентом и откройте ее простым просмотрщиком изображений, если лесенка приутствует, что то делать смысла нет.

Comment: Я попробую, но думаю не в этом дело.  На любом эмуляторе из AVD manager та же самая лесенка,  а монитор то всё гладко воспроизводит

Comment: Попробовал. На телефоне из галереи градиент отличный, а на в приложении градиент такой как на preview картинки в галерее.

Comment: Возможно [эта статья](http://thetechnocafe.com/make-a-moving-gradient-background-in-android/?utm_source=androiddevdigest) поможет вам сделать нормальный градиент в качестве фона. Часть про анимации можно пропустить.

Answer (score 1):

То, в какой папке (с каким квалификатором) находится изображение с градиентом, оказывает наименьшее влияние на качество изображения, если качество оригинала высокое. Для того, чтобы градиент был плавный, нужно использовать изображение 32-бит, параметры вывода изображения: `ARGB_8888`, `antialiasing` и `dithering`.

Поскольку вы не указали, каким образом вы обрабатываете или выводите изображение, несколько примеров установки параметров.

программно:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

разметка:

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:antialias="true"
   android:dither="true"
   android:src="@drawable/background" />
```

То есть данные параметры можно выставить и программно и через атрибуты виджета.

Подробнее [о влиянии параметров](http://www.curious-creature.com/2010/12/08/bitmap-quality-banding-and-dithering/), установленных для `Bitmap` на качество картинки

Comment: Пока что ничего не понимаю. В фотошопе нажав Save for Web можно сохранить в png-24 + поставив галочку на Transparency. В интернете прочитал, что с прозрачностью и получается 32 бита. Ну вот далее загруженный bitmap.getConfig(); оказалось он по умолчанию  ARGB_8888, об этом же  я прочитал в статье ,что вы приложили. Но изображение ,которое в виндовс с плавным градиентом, после загрузки в битмап стало с резким градиентом, хотя  ARGB_8888. Хотя я наверно кое что путаю.. png - 24 это наверно значит с глубиной цвета 24. А в фотошопе холст  с параметром 8 бит.. Попробую повысить качество холста

Comment: И я не нашел где можно программно загружаемому изображению назначить ARGB_8888, antialiasing и dithering. И зачем вообще нужны методы Bitmap.createBitmap() ? я же с помощью них не могу создать битмап с загрузкой в него изображения из drawble например. В зарание никогда не известы высота и ширина, это будет зависеть от телефона, какой высоты битмап использовать.

Comment: оказывается png и jpeg не бывают более чем 24 битные. Кажется вы меня обманули , что для качественного градиента нужно 32 битное изображение.. Но факт, что имеющееся изображение еще больше сжимается.

Comment: @Turalllb 32 бита - по 8 бит на цвет (r, g и b) и 8 бит - альфа (прозрачность). PNG может иметь альфа канал.

Comment: Ну значит так и выходит, что выбирая в фотошопе холст с 8 бит , я получаю по 8 бит на канал. Это и есть самое высокое качество для png или jpeg, который мы используем для графики в андроид. Ну и остается вопрос, почему после загрузки в битмап, так сильно теряется качество, если он загружается в ARGB_8888. И не понятно как программно загружаемому изображению задать другие атрибуты